# How to store in Array the parent IDs of elements with the same CLASS and display in alert these stored IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an existing website which limits me to touch HTML code. In the code below, there are 3 rows with the same CLASS (sameRow),.Row numbers may differ from case to case. Inside each row contains DIV with unique ID and a corresponding SELECT element with the same CLASS (sameSelect).

My target output is to be able create a JS/Jquery code to store these unique div IDs individually in the array and display each ID in the alert. Currently, my code below is displaying only the ID of the first DIV.  The second and the third is not displayed. What could be wrong in my code?

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Fiddle link here -> https://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/crkLgxhd/

HTML:

```
<div class="sameRow">
    <div id="uniquediv1">
        <select class="sameSelect">
            <option>1</option>
            <option selected>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="sameRow">
    <div id="uniquediv2">
        <select class="sameSelect">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option selected>4</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="sameRow">
    <div id="uniquediv3">
        <select class="sameSelect">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option  value="6" selected>6</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var optionValue = new Array();
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.sameRow').length;
    alert("there are " + rows + " rows");
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
        optionValue[i] = $(".sameSelect").parent().attr("id");
        alert("array row number " + i + " is " + optionValue[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use  `eq`

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var optionValue = new Array();
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.sameRow').length;
  alert("there are " + rows + " rows");
  for(i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
   optionValue[i] = $(".sameSelect").parent().eq(i).attr("id");
   alert("array row number " + i + " is " + optionValue[i]);
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sameRow">
  <div id="uniquediv1">
   <select class="sameSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div class="sameRow">
  <div id="uniquediv2">
   <select class="sameSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option selected>4</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div class="sameRow">
  <div id="uniquediv3">
   <select class="sameSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option  value="6" selected>6</option>
   </select>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's perfectly the missing code that I've been looking for.  Thank you so much @Akshay

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var optionValue = new Array();
        $('.sameRow').each(function(i){
            optionValue[i] = $(this).find('.sameSelect').parent().attr("id");
            alert("array row number " + (i + 1) + " is " + optionValue[i]);
        });
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/crkLgxhd/1/)

I think in this case no need for array you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.sameRow').each(function(i){
            var getID = $(this).find('.sameSelect').parent().attr("id");
            alert("array row number " + (i + 1) + " is " + getID);
        });
    });
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/crkLgxhd/2/)

Comment: @Mohamed-Yosef - this code should still work for some divs.  Though the div IDs are uniquely generated and sometimes has different first few letters.  So it may not work with other divs. That's why I'm storing the div ID using sameRow class as reference. But I still want to say thank you.